# How To Learn Mathematics Basics

Tags: arithmetic, self-learning, book-recommendation, learning, reference-works

I wanna learn mathematics from zero to advanced which books should I read and which websites should I visit?

Comment: How basic ? How advance ?(and also in advance levels , there is not one field and one type of math so your question cannot be properly answered )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courant-Robbins, "what is Mathematics"

https://www.ams.org/notices/200111/rev-blank.pdf
https://www.google.com/books/edition/What_is_Mathematics/_kYBqLc5QoQC?hl=en
https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183504823

Answer (score 0):

I took quick look at your profile and some of your other questions on Stack Overflow.

I admire your zeal, and your fearless attitude of just "jumping into" the material.

That being said, I want to stress that the world of Mathematics (just as with software development), is a vast vast ocean. Study any one of these for a lifetime, and you will barely have scratched the surface.

Read more and you will discover that for each answered question, ten new ones pop up, and you will realize soon enough that you only grasp a tiny drop in a vast sea of the unknown.

There is no way to learn "all of math -- zero to advanced". You learn a little about a particular topic, often you go back and learn the same topic over and over with ever-increasing depth. You dabble a little outside your area of expertise.

Start with math that might be interesting for web development (google discrete math), if that interests you, but be warned that a great deal of web dev work requires very little math, and your time might be better spent elsewhere.

All the best of luck!

Comment: Thanks, bro, I am very interested in web dev and also physics